# How to join on JSON keys values

Tags: mysql, json, join, inner-join

There is a `users` table

```
id  name    role  points
1   abc     admin  50
2   xyz     writer  25
3   efg     student  10
4   ghi     x_role   7
5   abc2     admin   23
```

and another `participants` table

```
id  participants
1   {"admin":[1], "writer":[2], "student": [], "x_role": []}
2   {"admin":[1,5], "writer":[], "student": [3], "x_role": [4]}
```

Now i have to calculate each participant scores based on values of **admin+writer+all roles** present in user table.

**Result should be**

```
Participants_id  Score

2                90
1                75
```

Comment: I've updated my question and i hope u'll get it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution:

```
-- detailled result
SELECT p.id, GROUP_CONCAT(u.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS participants, SUM(u.points) AS score
FROM participants p INNER JOIN users u ON JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(participants, CONCAT("$.", u.role)), CAST(u.id AS JSON), '$') = 1
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.id

-- expected result
SELECT p.id AS Participants_id, SUM(u.points) AS Score
FROM participants p INNER JOIN users u ON JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(participants, CONCAT("$.", u.role)), CAST(u.id AS JSON), '$') = 1
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.id
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9d4aeb72b02329201ff837911a1de95e)

Comment: Have you actually tried this one, Sebastian?  In any case, this JSON string represents a one-to-many relationship which really ought to be expressed in the database itself, even if the JSON-string text also needs to be retained.  This promises to be a *slow-w-w-w* query ...

Comment: if there will be more than 5 roles than i don't think this will be optimal solution

Comment: @SebastianBrosch i've added the result